# Edit txt file on button click vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to save 2 lines of numbers into a txt file and I want to add an integer of 1 on the first line and add 7 on the second line when I click a button.

So if I clicked the button once and opened the txt file it would look like this:

```
1 
7
```

and if I clicked it twice it would look like this:

```
2
14
```

I have the following code which i know is wrong as it keeps adding new lines instead of editing the existing lines.

```
Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("stats.txt", True)
        file.WriteLine(+1)
        file.WriteLine(+7)
        file.Close()
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try first reading the lines from the file, casting the values to integer and then rewriting to the file:

```
Dim Lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("stats.txt")       'Returns an array of string with one element for each line. In your case 2 elements in total
Dim FirstNewNumber As Integer = CInt(Lines(0)) + 1              'Cast the first element, aka the first line, to integer and add 1
Dim SecondNewNumber As Integer = CInt(Lines(1)) + 7             'Cast the second element, aka the second line, to integer and add 7
IO.File.WriteAllText("stats.txt", FirstNewNumber.ToString & _
                     vbNewLine & _
                     SecondNewNumber.ToString)                  'Concatenate the string representations with & and insert a Newline character in between
```

Always remember to use the correct data types for your variables. If you use the `+` operator on strings it will in the best of cases concatenate the to string (aka `"1" + "3"` will result in `"13"`) and in the worst case not work at all.
If you want to use arithmetic calculations use a numeric data type like integer. And be sure to enable `Option Strict` in your project to avoid mistakes by forcing correct data type casting. It might seems bothersome at first but trust me, it's more than worth it.

Comment: Wow thanks for the fast and very informative response, as you might have already guessed I am new to VB and you have just helped me out ALOT!, Thanks! I will save your advice just in-case I need to use it again. :)

Answer (score 0):

'Can Try something like this

```
    Dim NewDocument As New List(Of String) 'List to save current and edited lines

    Using sr As New StreamReader("stats.txt")
        While Not sr.EndOfStream

            Dim Line1 As String = sr.ReadLine
            Dim Line2 As String = sr.ReadLine

            Line1 = Line1 + 1
            Line2 = Line2 + 7

            NewDocument.Add(Line1)
            NewDocument.Add(Line2)


        End While


    End Using


    If System.IO.File.Exists("stats,txt") Then
        System.IO.File.Delete(Filename)
    End If

    Using sw As New StreamWriter("stats.txt")
        For Each line As String In HL7Doc
            sw.WriteLine(line)
        Next
    End Using
```